# Tensorflow GradientDescentOptimizer - how does it connect to tf.Variables?

Tags: python, tensorflow

[Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/train.html#GradientDescentOptimizer)

I'm just curious how you tell it to minimize which variables. For example in this linear regression code, TF does fine optimizing weights/bias without being told the names of the variables:

```
y = W * x + b

cost_func = tf.nn.l2_loss(y_ - y)  # squared error

trainer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost_func)
```

How does tensorflow know I want it to update `W` and `b`? Does it just see that those are the only Variables in the session?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It takes them from `tf.trainable_variables()` which includes all variables created with `trainable=True` flag (the default)